# Combining JQuery variable + template variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am trying to pre-pend a template variable to a JS variable. I currently have:

```
var filename = some_variable
$('#file_extension_input').val(filename);
```

And it is populating the following form field:

```
<input type="input" name="key" value="" id="file_extension_input">
```

With a resulting outcome would be, for example, `value="test.jpg"`

How would I pre-pend a template variable to the `.val` so it would be something like this:

```
var filename = some_variable
$('#file_extension_input').val( {{username}} + filename);
```

And the resulting oucome would be, for example, `value="johnsmith/test.jpg"`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var prefix = '{{username|escapejs}}';
var filename = some_variable;
$('#file_extension_input').val(prefix + filename);
```